# My PHP query is returning weird characters like "E�". why?

Tags: php, html, sql, firebird

My data is stored in firebird database.
The actual data is  "E…" but when queried in PHP it shows as  "E�"
How to get correct data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP MySQL database strange characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910549/php-mysql-database-strange-characters)

Comment: @Triby That question applies to MySQL, so although the underlying problem is similar, the solutions will not be exactly the same.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are using connection character set NONE on a system which uses UTF-8 as the default character set, while the data is stored in a different character set (eg windows-1252).

Comment: The solution is having all your data sources using the same character set (php, html, database, etc.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows how you connect to Firebird and output the data, the DDL of the relevant tables would also be helpful, especially whether or not the database columns have an explicit character set or not.

Comment: @Triby - this is a quest in futility, given that different languages have different ideas what is proper character set inside and outside of application. Even the same application run on Windows and Linux might think different character sets are "native choice". The solution is **specifying** the character set in the connection properties and optionally in the text column declarations (if not, they would borrow those from the connection), so Firebird knows which way to interprete incoming text and which way to convert outcoming text.